# Game transfer from PC to Android (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, 2d-games, platform

I have a question.
Since I was making my game(2D) in UNITY to work for PC, and now I want to switch platform for ANDROID.
So my question is, **can I put both controls for pc and android in one  script**? Like, just to add those codes beneath, or there is some other ways?

I appreciate every help!

Comment: Your game won't *play* identically on Windows and Android, will it? One has a keyboard and a mouse, the other has touch input. The platform specific difference will probably be on the order of files, not of lines or functions.

Comment: It won't be played identically, but would love to have the game and for Android and for PC. So that either people can play on PC or Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preprocessing directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) to use different code for different platforms within the same script.

For example:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    // Android code here.
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE
    // PC code here.
#endif
```

When building, Unity compiles only the relevant code for the selected platform and completely ignores the other parts.

[image]

Your IDE will also grey out the excluded part in the above code:

[image]

Comment: So basically I have to put #if UNITY_ANDROID #endif and #if UNITY_STANDALONE #endif , and inside to put the controls I want to use (movement)?

Comment: Yes, you should do that.

Comment: I am not great at coding yet, that's why I am asking stupid questions.. Can i put this code in an already existing script or should i make the a one and append to any object in game (add component) ?

Comment: And yes, since i have already my movement scripts for the PC version, shall i just add for ANDROID, or it has to be done by that way you showed me and put both codes again?

Comment: No worries, you will improve in time. No, you don't need to create a new script. Just enclose your code for PC with #if UNITY_STANDALONE and append the Anrdoid version within #if UNITY_ANDROID in the same script.